# LAN network won't work in Linux but works on windows

Tags: 13.04, networking, lan

I have a question. Please forgive if this has already been answered:

I am trying to connect some computers to the LAN of my office and I found out that the Ubuntu 13.10 computers won't connect to the LAN unless I manually setup a fixed IP number for them. If I connect a windows computer to the same wired network, works with no problems.

Do you have any idea what this could be happening? Why the automatic DHCP seems to work fine in windows but no in linux?

The computers I'm using are Lenovo ThinkCentre Edge 72 with Ubuntu 13.04

Ethernet Controler: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RT8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controler (rev 06)

Intel Pentium Dual-Core G2030( 3.00GHz )
Intel Integrated HD Graphics
4.0GB PC3-12800 DDR3 SDRAM 1600 MHz
500GB 7200 rpm

Comment: Check if dhclient is running on the ubuntu machine e.g. pgrep dhclient .

Comment: I believe it is a bug in the driver r8169 having to do with autonegotiation. If it works as expected with a static IP, I'd do so. The fixes for the driver r8169 seem to be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

The linux kernel uses "generic drivers" for your computer. Where as Windows requires explicit installation of your drivers. Hence some of the functionality that you get in windows might not be available in ubuntu.

You can go to the website of your NIC card vendor and check for drivers that can be installed in ubuntu. Reinstall the driver. All will be fixed.

I had faced this problem with my laptop which used "Realtek" NIC card. When I reinstalled the driver with my kernel everything worked.